# Graph API for C#: 401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials. on /planner/plans

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

I am working with Graph API. I don´t have too much experience with this. I am creating an application to add a plan into an existing group.

So, I have registered an application with this permissions (You can see that these are Delegated permissions) :

[image]

Then, I have written this code to Add a new Planner (You will see that I am using a token) using this endpoint /planner/plans .

```
var configAuthority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/8318d89e-e4db-471e-85da-b34ae833813f";
            IConfidentialClientApplication confidentialClientApplication = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
                                  .Create(ConfigurationParameters.ClientID)
                                  .WithTenantId(ConfigurationParameters.TenantID)
                                  .WithClientSecret(ConfigurationParameters.ClientSecret)
                                  .WithAuthority(new Uri(configAuthority))
                                  .Build();
            ClientCredentialProvider authProvider = new ClientCredentialProvider(confidentialClientApplication);
            string[] scopes = new string[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };
            AuthenticationResult accessToken = confidentialClientApplication.AcquireTokenForClient(scopes).ExecuteAsync().Result;
            GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(authProvider);
            List<HeaderOption> requestHeaders = new List<HeaderOption>() {
                            new HeaderOption("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken.AccessToken)
                };
            var existingsplanners = graphClient
                                        .Groups[createPlannerForGroupRequest.GroupId.ToString()]
                                        .Planner
                                        .Plans.
                                        Request(requestHeaders)
                                        .GetAsync()
                                        .Result;
            var planner = graphClient
                        .Groups[createPlannerForGroupRequest.GroupId.ToString()]
                        .Planner
                        .Plans
                        .Request(requestHeaders)
                        .AddAsync(new PlannerPlan { 
                            Title = createPlannerForGroupRequest.Name,
                            Owner = createPlannerForGroupRequest.GroupId.ToString(),
                            ODataType = null,
                        }).Result;
```

The result for both requests are the same.

```
Code: UnknownError
Message: <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"/>
<title>401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials.</title>
<style type="text/css">
<!--
body{margin:0;font-size:.7em;font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;background:#EEEEEE;}
fieldset{padding:0 15px 10px 15px;} 
h1{font-size:2.4em;margin:0;color:#FFF;}
h2{font-size:1.7em;margin:0;color:#CC0000;} 
h3{font-size:1.2em;margin:10px 0 0 0;color:#000000;} 
#header{width:96%;margin:0 0 0 0;padding:6px 2% 6px 2%;font-family:"trebuchet MS", Verdana, sans-serif;color:#FFF;
background-color:#555555;}
#content{margin:0 0 0 2%;;}
.content-container{background:#FFF;width:96%;margin-top:8px;padding:10px;;}
-->
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="header"><h1>Server Error</h1></div>
<div id="content">
 <div class="content-container"><fieldset>
  <h2>401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials.</h2>
  <h3>You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied.</h3>
 </fieldset></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>

Inner error:
    AdditionalData:
    request-id: 19c09b10-1694-4201-85a9-ba3639e1dba5
    date: 2020-06-03T07:29:59
ClientRequestId: 19c09b10-1694-4201-85a9-ba3639e1dba5
```

As you can see, there is a permissions issue even if it is a delegated permissions on Azure AD. Should I wait 24 hours? Should I change the token requester method instead of use AcquireTokenForClient?

The same method works on Graph Explorer. Creation of Team instance for an existing group works fine.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you use client credential grant flow in your code, but the graph api just support delegated permissions. So we need to use authorization code grant flow or username/password grant flow. (By the way, we recommend authorization code flow rather than username/password flow)

For authorization code flow, please refer to this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/choose-authentication-providers?context=graph%2Fapi%2F1.0&view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=CS#authorization-code-provider) with the code sample in it.

```
IConfidentialClientApplication confidentialClientApplication = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
    .Create(clientId)
    .WithRedirectUri(redirectUri)
    .WithClientSecret(clientSecret) // or .WithCertificate(certificate)
    .Build();

AuthorizationCodeProvider authProvider = new AuthorizationCodeProvider(confidentialClientApplication, scopes);
```

For username/password flow, you can refer to this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/choose-authentication-providers?context=graph%2Fapi%2F1.0&view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=CS#usernamepassword-provider) with the code sample in it.

```
IPublicClientApplication publicClientApplication = PublicClientApplicationBuilder
            .Create(clientId)
            .WithTenantId(tenantID)
            .Build();

UsernamePasswordProvider authProvider = new UsernamePasswordProvider(publicClientApplication, scopes);

GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(authProvider);

User me = await graphClient.Me.Request()
                .WithUsernamePassword(email, password)
                .GetAsync();
```

**Update:**

You can do some changes by following the steps below, then you don't need to provide the client_secret in your code and it also will not show the error message `The request body must contain the following parameter: 'client_assertion' or 'client_secret'`.

1. Go to your app registered in azure ad and click "Authentication" --> "Add a platform" --> "Mobile and desktop applications".
   [image]
2. Choose the first one as the "Redirect URIs".
   [image]
3. Scroll down and check if this configuration is "yes"(if "no", please change it to "yes"), then click "Save".
   [image]

Comment: Hello Hury,I have tried to follow this guide https://laurakokkarinen.com/authenticating-to-office-365-apis-with-a-certificate-step-by-step/ to create my certificate. Also, I have change to HttpClient and I got this error when request groups/GUID/planner/plans StatusCode: 403, ReasonPhrase: 'Forbidden', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent,  I will share my full code in the next answer. Thank you!

Comment: Hi @JoseLuisSuarezCabrera The guide link you provided shows how to authenticate by certificate but the graph api you request required the permission with "delegated" type. So we can not use certificate to do authentication and also can not use client credential flow to do authentication as I mentioned in my answer above. We can just use authorization code flow or username/password flow to do the authentication. I have provided the two code samples in my solution above, please follow one of these two code samples.

Comment: Thanks I will check it now. I have posted the code some seconds ago, but it was with Application Permissions in App registration. :)

Comment: Hi again Hury! I created a new App registration with all delegated permissions needed (Group.ReadAll and WriteAll) I have gotten the same response from the server, I uploaded the same certificate. I have decode the Access token but it looks like the application permissions token. I mean, I cannot see that my user is executing the request as the Graph Explorer: {
  "aud": "https://graph.microsoft.com",
  "iss": "https://sts.windows.n/",
  "iat": 1591338085,
  "nbf": 1591338085,
  "exp": 1591341985,
  "aio": "42dgYFiSdfzmOY0km9AlB1ikHmyYCQA=",
  "app_displayname": "...0506Delegated",

Comment: @JoseLuisSuarezCabrera If you use certificate to do authentication and get the access token or use client credential flow to do authenticate and get the access token, you can just get the token with application permissions in it(the permissions should be in the `role` field in your decoded token). You need to use authorization code flow or username/password flow to do authentication and get the access token, parse this access token you can get the delegated permission in it(the permissions should be in the `scp` field in your decoded token).

Comment: Hello @Hury Shen, I have gotten some errors again. I posted the code in a different answer. I am sorry, but I guess there is something I did not get it. Thank you ;)